# Chat entre 2 usuarios

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, websocket

estoy intentando realizar un chat en el que puedan comunicarse 2 usuarios diferentes mediante un servidor.

El registro de usuarios ya está realizado!

Mi codigo actual del xat es el siguiente, un input que al enviar un valor es escrito en el div, que es el chat.

Necesitaría algún código de ayuda, como ejemplo para poder completar el chat, ya sea con sse o con websockets.
Agradecería mucho la ayuda, de que me ayudarais a como poder completarlo.

Código a continuación:

````
    <div class="contenido_petit_xat">
        <!-- <div class="error-txt">Error mensaje</div> -->
        <div class="contenidor_pantalla_xat" >
            <div id="xat" class="pantalla"></div>
        </div>
   
        <div class="contenidor_input_xat">

            <input type="text" id="missatge" name="missatge">
            <!-- <input type="submit" id="enviar">Enviar mis</input> -->
            <button id="btnXat">Enviar</button>

        </div>    
    </div>   
</div>

<script> 
    var missatge = document.getElementById("missatge");
    var xat = document.getElementById("xat");
    var btnXat = document.getElementById("btnXat");

    function enviar(){
        if(missatge.value != "" && missatge.lenght !=0){
            //msg crea un div
            var msg = document.createElement('div');
            //Li donem una classe a msg
            msg.classList.add('mis');
            //Obtenim el text enviat
            msg.innerText = missatge.value;
            //Enganxem el text enviat al xat
            xat.appendChild(msg);
            

            //el misatge queda en blanc
            missatge.value="";
        }
    }

    //click a enviar crida funcio                 
    btnXat.onclick = enviar;
    //enter crida funcio
    missatge.onkeyup= function (e){
            if(e.keyCode==13){
            enviar();
            
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Ejemplos hay muchos y solo necesitas preguntarle a san google, que todo lo sabe. Primer resultado buscando [php websocket](https://www.natapuntes.es/websockets-con-php-javascript/). Lo más seguro es que tu pregunta termine cerrada por no estar basada en un problema concreto, siendo demasiado amplia como para una respuesta simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
Necesitaría algún código de ayuda, como ejemplo para poder completar el chat, 
ya sea con sse o con websockets
```

podrías guiarte con este ejemplo de https://github.com/sanwebe/Chat-Using-WebSocket-and-PHP-Socket.git hecho con websockets.

Fragmento de Server.php:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; //host
$port = '9000'; //port
$null = NULL; //null var

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

...
```

script de index.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    //create a new WebSocket object.
    var msgBox = $('#message-box');
    var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9000/demo/server.php";  
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 
    
    websocket.onopen = function(ev) { // connection is open 
        msgBox.append('<div class="system_msg" style="color:#bbbbbb">Welcome to my "Demo WebSocket Chat box"!</div>'); //notify user
    }
    // Message received from server
    websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
        var response        = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data
        
        var res_type        = response.type; //message type
        var user_message    = response.message; //message text
        var user_name       = response.name; //user name
        var user_color      = response.color; //color

        switch(res_type){
            case 'usermsg':
                msgBox.append('<div><span class="user_name" style="color:' + user_color + '">' + user_name + '</span> : <span class="user_message">' + user_message + '</span></div>');
                break;
            case 'system':
                msgBox.append('<div style="color:#bbbbbb">' + user_message + '</div>');
                break;
        }
        msgBox[0].scrollTop = msgBox[0].scrollHeight; //scroll message 

    };
    
    websocket.onerror   = function(ev){ msgBox.append('<div class="system_error">Error Occurred - ' + ev.data + '</div>'); }; 
    websocket.onclose   = function(ev){ msgBox.append('<div class="system_msg">Connection Closed</div>'); }; 

    //Message send button
    $('#send-message').click(function(){
        send_message();
    });
    
    //User hits enter key 
    $( "#message" ).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
      if(event.which==13){
          send_message();
      }
    });
    
    //Send message
    function send_message(){
        var message_input = $('#message'); //user message text
        var name_input = $('#name'); //user name
        
        if(message_input.val() == ""){ //empty name?
            alert("Enter your Name please!");
            return;
        }
        if(message_input.val() == ""){ //emtpy message?
            alert("Enter Some message Please!");
            return;
        }

        //prepare json data
        var msg = {
            message: message_input.val(),
            name: name_input.val(),
            color : '<?php echo $colors[$color_pick]; ?>'
        };
        //convert and send data to server
        websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));    
        message_input.val(''); //reset message input
    }
</script>
```

Si el enlace llegara a ser inútil, actualizaré la respuesta, espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/379538)